# How would you switch through kCL error in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, core-location

How would you switch through kCL error in Swift?

My attempt below says `Use of unresolved identifier 'kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult'`:

```
switch error {
case kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult:  print("\(#function): No results")
default: print("\(#function): Error reports \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error` has to be cast to `CLError` so the `code` property can be accessed, see as follows:

```
if let error = error as? CLError {
    switch error.code {
       case CLError.Code.geocodeFoundPartialResult:  print("\(#function): No results")
       default: print("\(#function): Error reports \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Example:

```
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: 23.8759, longitude: 90.3795)
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {placemarks, error in

        if let lvError = error as? CLError {
            NSLog("Geocode failed with error: \(lvError)")
            let message: String
            switch lvError.code {
            case .geocodeFoundNoResult:
                message = "kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult"
            case .geocodeCanceled:
                message = "kCLErrorGeocodeCanceled"
            case .geocodeFoundPartialResult:
                message = "kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult"
            default: message = (lvError as NSError).description
            }
            return
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but odd enough, error has no code property: Compiler says: `Value of type 'Error' has no member 'code'`

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca from `error` to `(error as NSError)`. and check my updated answer

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca it's not working or helping for you. if not then i surly deleted my answer

Comment: Chokran a 5ay, your answer helped me to find out the issue. I have updated your answer to make the code 100% accurate.